# How do I keep the help-text when creating .p file?

Tags: matlab

I have a `m.`-file with a function inside using "new>function" and name the function "foo".

```matlab
>> type foo.m

function [outputArg1,outputArg2] = foo(inputArg1,inputArg2)
%FOO Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
outputArg1 = inputArg1;
outputArg2 = inputArg2;
end

>> help foo
 foo Summary of this function goes here
    Detailed explanation goes here
```

After creating a `.p`-file, however, the help text is not available anymore.

```matlab
>> pcode foo
>> delete foo.m
>> help foo
foo is a function.
```

Can I obfuscate/protect my code, while still having help text available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design `pcode()` only contains parsed MATLAB code. This means that any comments in the code, including the help section, will not be available after obfuscation. The [officially promoted way](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100178-how-do-i-include-help-with-my-p-files-from-matlab) of including a help section after obfuscation is to write a separate .M-file with the same name containing the help section. Thus, save a file `foo.m`:

```matlab
%%FOO does bar
%
% Inputs:
%
% More help text
% Blabla
```

Note that you don't have to actually call `foo.p` inside your `foo.m` function:

> If both a .M and .P file exist, MATLAB will call the P-file for execution, so the .M file only needs to contain the help comments.

Converting .M files to .P files is just *obfuscation* not encryption or compilation. This means that the possibility to de-obfuscate exists. See [protect your source code](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/protect-your-source-code.html) by The MathWorks (emphasis mine):

> Deploy as P-code — Convert some or all of your source code files to a content-obscured form called a P-code file (from its .p file extension), and distribute your application code in this format. When MATLAB P-codes a file, the file is obfuscated **not encrypted**. While the content in a .p file is difficult to understand, **it should not be considered secure**. It is not recommended that you P-code files to protect your intellectual property.

---

As a side-note, something similar can be seen when calling the source code of built-in functions, e.g. `edit sum` shows nothing but the help for `sum`, not even a `function` keyword on top.